# What is - - > operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript

While refactoring I mistakenly put two dash `--` before `>` and the code seems to work without any error. I checked [MDN Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) page but could not find a relevant definition. Can you please let me know what is this operator called.

```js
function checkSitOccupancy(n) {
  while (n --> 0)
    console.log(n);
}
checkSitOccupancy(2)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement

Comment: `--` and `>` are two separate operators.  Space or no space, they are not one operator.

Comment: `n--` means `n=n-1` , then you use the bigger than operator ´>´ afterwards

Answer (score 1):

`while (n-- > 0)` means "while decremented value of n is greater than zero"

Answer (score 0):

There is no `-->` operator. You are just decreasing `n` and comparing if > 0

Answer (score 0):

It is the decrement operator.

It decrements the value of n and compares it with a greater than operator

Answer (score -1):

That's the decrement operator, subtraction's analog to `++`.

EDIT: In your case above, you've squeezed a decrement and greater than sign together, making them appear to be a single operator; they're not, as javascript doesn't need the white space.